# hierarchical report , based on TFS query

Tags: tfs, report

I need to create a hierarchical report , based on TFS query .

Each work Item returned by the query has two fields :

Description – text  ( default system.description field )
Level – a string filed , representing hierarchy level ( like 1.2 , 1.2.1 … )  ( my custom filed )
For example as a result of executing query I got the following results :
[image]

Now I need to create a report , which will display this data with indentation according to level .

[image]

Preferable output format is WORD , but other options are also possible .

I don't have any knowledge in tfs reports , please give a guidelines of how achieve it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out TeamSpec, which integrates TFS with Word.  There is a feature where you can import work items to a Word document in a specified format using a query.  A link to the feature can be found at http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamspec/how-to/importing-work-items-from-searches-and-queries.aspx  A 90 day trial can be found at http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/download.aspx#teamspec